# Android WebView click DOM Element

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have web application and i want use this app in Android WebView.Already enabled JavaScriptpage loading and ***$(document).ready()*** functions are working.

But ***click()*** function not working, for example;

```js
$('#btnOdaNo').click(function(){
$('.odaNoWrapper').hide();});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="odaNoWrapper">
  <input id="txtOdaNo" class="form-control form-control-lg numeric" type="text" placeholder="Lütfen bir oda numarası yazınız..." style="text-align: center;">
  <button class="btnCustom mt-5" id="btnOdaNo">Devam Et</button>
</div>
```

Comment: try to enable domstorage & java script, webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in **AndroidManifest**, because u use jquery script from internet

Comment: Already set the permissions for Internet usage in Android Project.